# Direct linux machine audio to java program

Tags: java, linux, pulseaudio

I need to write some java code that will listen to the audio that other processes produce. I've looked around and it seems I should use PulseAudio. If I am not mistaken, I need to define a sink that will be my java process, and tell the source (alsa?) to go there. I failed to find any details on how to do this.

And - what should I use on the java side? This gives me 0 mixers:

```
Info[] mis = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
for (Info mi : mis)
{
    System.out.println(mi.getName());
    System.out.println(mi.getVendor());
    System.out.println(mi.getDescription());
    System.out.println("---------------");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've managed to get this working. I am sure this can be done a bit shorter so fill free to correct me:

- Create a loopback sink: `sudo modprobe snd-aloop`
- Check the list of audio sinks: `aplay -l`. If you have a real sound card, the loopback will be card 1.
- Create (or edit) the .asoundrc file: `cat > ~/.asoundrc`.

Put this there:

```
pcm.!default {
 type hw
 card 1
 device 0
}
```

This will direct all processes starting from hereon to use the loopback for audio output.

- Install PulseAudio Volume Control: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`
- Open the Volume Control application and make sure the real card is not marked as fallback, and that the loopback is (under 'output').
- This will send the audio using the System.in stream to a java process: `arecord -D hw:1,1 -f cd | java -jar some-java-code.jar`